# Auto Div height depend on another one

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario I want Div2 height to resize depend on the content of Div3 
how I can do that ?

```
----------------------------------
.      DIV1                      .
. ---------   ------------------ .
. .       .   .                . .
. .  DIV2 .   .        DIV3    . .
. .       .   .                . .
. .       .   .                . .
. ---------   -----------------. .
.--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to display same height of both DIV2 and DIV3. By CSS you can do it as below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child_1">First Div content goes here</div>
    <div class="child_2">Second Div content goes here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
        width: 960px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    .child_1, .child_2 {
        padding-bottom: 1000px;
        margin-bottom: -1000px;
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    .child_1 {
        background: #f00;
    }

    .child_2 {
        background: #0f0;
    }
```

Code above will display your div height's equal if they have 1000px different in height as per code. you can change 1000px, if you think in some case difference could be more. It'll support in all browsers

Other wise you can use javascript for it. You need to find height of longest div and set same height in other div.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `display: table-cell` css property, though be warned, it's CSS3 and doesn't have a lot of support in anything older than IE8.

Example:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    display: table;
}
.div1 > div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;    
    display: table-cell;
}
.div3 {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97NJR/

Comment: its a very nice solution, but what if I already use float:left, can I stay use it or I must re design ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the CSS attribute `display: table-cell`. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz7m5/1/).

**EDIT**

Using floats, try this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz7m5/3/)
Or equally this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/PHCb9/). Both provide an elegant solution.

Comment: its a very nice solution, but what if I already use float:left, can I stay use it or I must re design ?

Comment: what if I want to make a div4 inside div3 and make it always on bottom ?