# div set height equal

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `div`s. How can I make them equal if the other `div` height adjust. I want all my `div`s to adjust its height even do they have less contents. like in the image even the `div` without data must be equal to others and set the read more at the bottom.

***HTML:***

```
<div class="column-wrapper">
   <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
      <h3>Features</h3>

      <ul>
         <li>Code blocking</li>
         <li>Code Wrapping</li>
         <li>Code Killing</li>
         <li>Code Sleeping</li>
      </ul>

      <span><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
   </div>

   <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
      <h3>Modules</h3>

      <ul>
         <li>Barking Around The house</li>
         <li>Loving the Cats</li>
         <li>Floating The points</li>
         <li>Coding The Sleepers</li>
      </ul>

      <span><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
   </div>

   <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
      <h3>Idont knows</h3>
      <span><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.column-wrapper {
   padding-top: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
}

.column-wrapper div {
    display: inline-table; 
    margin: 2px;
}

.column-small {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%; 
    min-width: 250px; 
    height: auto;
} 

.column-small span {
   float: right;
} 

.column-small ul {
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 240px;
}

.column-small ul li {
    text-align: left;  
}

.column-small li { 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    text-indent: -30px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you have set column-small height to auto; so its now on browser to calculate the height of divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first part looks like a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235116/1902425

to your second part: if you're doing it with js, your height is dynamically calculated, so you can postion your "Read More" link wir `position: absolute` little example:

```
<div class="column-small">
      <div class="column-content">
          <h3>Idont knows</h3>
          <p>Your content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="readmore"><a href="#">Read more</a></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.column-small {
     position: relative;
     height: 240px;
}
.readmore {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***CSS:***

```
.column-wrapper { overflow: hidden; }

.column-small {
   float: left;
   margin: 20px;
   background-color: red;
   padding-bottom: 1000px;
   margin-bottom: -1000px;
}

.column-small span { float: right; }

.column-small ul {
   margin-top: -10px;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 240px;
}

.column-small ul li { text-align: left; }

.column-small li {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 5px;
   text-indent: -30px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div class="column-wrapper">
   <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
      <h3>Features</h3>

      <ul>
         <li>Code blocking</li>
         <li>Code Wrapping</li>
         <li>Code Killing</li>
         <li>Code Sleeping</li>
      </ul>

      <span><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
   </div>

   <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
      <h3>Modules</h3>

      <ul>
         <li>Barking Around The house</li>
         <li>Loving the Cats</li>
         <li>Floating The points</li>
         <li>Coding The Sleepers</li>
      </ul>

      <span><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
   </div>

   <div class="column-small border  border-top"> 
      <h3>Idont knows</h3>
      <span><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yah its working but when i use it to my code.the design mess up. and the .column-small div become higher.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height for `.column-small div`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.column-small{
    height: inherit !important;
}
```